# How to compare values of actual key and the previous one?

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, compare

I have a dictionary and inside of the values are lists which contain 2 numbers.

For example:

```
z_n = {'1': [[4, 7], [7, 8], [7, 9], [6, 7]], '2': [[4, 5], [8, 10], [3, 4]]}
```

First I want to remove the number 7 of all lists inside of the value from the first key.

That works like this:

```
root = 7

# Iterating through dictionary z_n
for key, value in z_n.items():

    # Iterating through lists of values
    for lis in value:

        #
        if root in lis:

            # Removing 7 from the list
            lis.remove(root)
```

For the first key it will be like this:

```
z_n = {'1': [[4], [8], [9], [6]], '2': [[4, 5], [8, 10], [3, 4]]}
```

From the following keys now on I want to compare their values with the values from the previous key and remove them again from each list.

In this case I want to remove 4, 8, 9 and 6 if they are in `'2': [[4, 5], [8, 10], [3, 4]]` so that it will be like this:
`'2': [[5],[10],[3]]`.

How is it possible to compare each value of the actual key to all values from the previous key and remove them if they are inside both?

Comment: What happens if the sub-lists for key value '1' contain more than one value after removal of 'root'?

Comment: This is not possible because all sub-lists from first key will always contain root (7). And it is not possible for sub-lists of following keys to contain root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
import itertools

def remove_func(sublist, remove_list):
    new_sublist = []
    for i in sublist:
        temp = []
        for j in i:
            if j not in remove_list:
                temp.append(j)
        new_sublist.append(temp)
        
    return new_sublist
    

z_n = {'1': [[4, 7], [7, 8], [7, 9], [6, 7]], '2': [[4, 5], [8, 10], [3, 4]]}

remove_list = [7]
for key, value in z_n.items():
    z_n[key] = remove_func(z_n[key], remove_list )
    remove_list = list(itertools.chain(*z_n[key]))
    
print(z_n)
```

Output:

```
{'1': [[4], [8], [9], [6]], '2': [[5], [10], [3]]}
```

Comment: Actually this is genius! Would it be possible to do actually the same but to save sub-lists which only contain a single number only as the number? Like instead of [[4], [8], [9], [6]] it would be nice as [4, 8, 9, 6].

Comment: @maxwell_742 here `remove_list = list(itertools.chain(*z_n[key]))` saves flatten of list of lists, it means `[[4], [8], [9], [6]]` to `[4, 8, 9, 6]`.

Answer (score 0):

*Picking up from exactly where you are stuck*, i.e. I'm assuming you have removed number 7 from your first key in the dictionary.

You can first create a set for all the values for first key, then filter out the values in list of list of values in second key:

```py
values=set(x for v in z_n['1'] for x in v)
z_n['2'] = [[v for v in x if v not in values] for x in z_n['2']]

# z_n
{'1': [[4], [8], [9], [6]], '2': [[5], [10], [3]]}
```

Comment: That is a good idea, but I would like to avoid to address the keys by their names. Because the dictionary contains sometimes only up to 4 keys but other times more than 10 (of course with a lot more sub-lists then). And my goal was it to automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using sets:

```
z_n = {'1': [[4, 7], [7, 8], [7, 9], [6, 7]], '2': [[4, 5], [8, 10], [3, 4]]}

root = 7

s = {root}

for i, k in enumerate(z_n.keys()):
    z_n[k] = [list(set(e) - s) for e in z_n[k]]
    if i == 0:
        s = {e[0] for e in z_n[k]}

print(z_n)
```

**Output:**

```
{'1': [[4], [8], [9], [6]], '2': [[5], [10], [3]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
z_n['2'] = [[*(set(sum(z_n['1'], []))^set(val))&set(val),] for idx,val in enumerate(z_n['2'])]
```

OR

```
z_n['2'] = [[*set(sum(z_n['1'], [])).intersection(val).symmetric_difference(val),] for idx,val in enumerate(z_n['2'])]
```

Output:

```
{'1': [[4], [8], [9], [6]], '2': [[5], [10], [3]]}
```